# Can't push a file from local to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to push a file from local machine to s3. Heres the code

```
    ---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
  tasks:
  - name: install python boto3 for aws s3
    pip:
      name:
      - boto3
      - botocore
  - name: copy files to s3
    aws_s3: bucket={{ s3_bucket_name }} object={{ cluster_config_file }} src={{ k8s_config_file  }} mode=put
```

But getting this :-

```
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => changed=false
  msg: Local object for PUT does not exist
```

anything i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the path provided by the `k8s_config_file` is relative, and since Ansible starts looking from the path of the `playbook`, it can't find it. For example, If we defined our project like this:

```
.
├── ansible
│   └── collections
│       └── ansible_collections
├── ansible.cfg
├── files
│   └── example
├── inventory
├── playbooks
│   └── s3.yml
└── requirements.yml
```

And we were running the `s3.yml` playbook like this:

```sh
ansible-playbook playbook/s3.yml
```

If will fail if the `src` value of the `aws_s3` module was defined as the relative path `./files/example`. If, instead, we provide an absolute path for the file or a relative path from the directory of the `playbook`: `../files/example`; it will work.